# mysqli_real_escape_string() error

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting an error message such as:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\lr\core\functions\general.php  on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysqli_result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\lr\core\functions\users.php:4 Stack
>   trace: #0  C:\xampp\htdocs\lr\login.php(13): user_exists(NULL) #1
>   {main} thrown in  C:\xampp\htdocs\lr\core\functions\users.php on line
>   4"

This is my code for users.php:

```
function user_exists($User) {
    $User = sanitize($User);
    return (mysqli_result(mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT('Id') FROM 
                                       'members' WHERE 'User' = '$User'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
function user_active($User) {
    $User = sanitize($User);
    return (mysqli_result(mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT('Id') FROM 
                                      'members' WHERE 'User' = '$User' AND 'active' = 1"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
function Id_from_User($User) {
    $User = sanitize($User);
    return mysqli_result(mysqli_query("SELECT 'Id' FROM 'members' 
                                    WHERE 'User' ='$User'"), 0, 'Id');
}
function login($User, $Password) {
    $Id   = Id_from_User($User);
    $User = sanitize($User);
    return (mysqli_result(mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT('Id') FROM 
                                      'members' WHERE 'User' = '$User' AND 'Password' = 'Password'"), 0) == 1) ? $Id : false;
}
```

My code for init.php

```
session_start();
require('database/connect.php');
require('functions/users.php');
require('functions/general.php');
$errors = array();
```

My code for login.php

```
include('core/init.php');
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $User     = $_POST['User'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];
    if (empty($User) === true || empty($Password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter a Username and Password';
    } else if (user_exists($User) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that Username. Have you 
                                            registered?';
    } else {
        $login = login($User, $Password);
        if ($login === false) {
            $errors[] = 'That Username/Password combination is 
                                             incorrect';
        } else {
            echo 'ok!';
            $_SESSION['Id'] = $login;
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
    print_r($errors);
}
```

My code for general.php

```
function sanitize($data) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($data);
}
```

my code for connect.php

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "underthehat");
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db 
                                          database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($conn) . PHP_EOL;
mysqli_close($conn);
```

and Finally my code for index.php

```
include('core/init.php');
include('includes/head.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['Id'])) {
    echo 'Logged in';
} else {
    echo 'Not logged in';
}

echo "<html><body>";
include('includes/header.php');
include('includes/aside.php');
include('includes/footer.php');
echo "</body></html>";
```

I have been trying to figure out my login with the database that I have created and errors is all I get.

Comment: your code is failing on way too many levels. I can't emphasize that enough

Comment: @Fred-ii- Rather than emphasizing, why don't you point the OP a few?

Comment: @EricWu If you went through their code at all, you would quickly find that there is not enough room in comments to outline them. That is NOT up to me to do that.......... not in this case. Did you not understand the part where I stated: *"Too many errors"*?

Comment: Plus, there are far too many duplicates for this for me to fetch. I doubt this question gets resolved. So I'll just vote to close as generic.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Believe me, I rarely flair out without a significant reason. The reason for which I thought some pointing out was necessary was because the _OP_ might not be aware of them (maybe check his rep).

Comment: I'm not sure how the posted error message could be confusing. Expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given. Look up the documentation for that method and see what 2 parameters it is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Your `mysqli_real_escape_string()` needs the connection variable as well;

So you need to pass the

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "underthehat");
```

above you `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and then include it in that tag;

```
return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data);
```

Comment: believe me, that's just the tip of the iceberg.You missed a LOT of stuff.

Comment: A second glance and you are so very correct once more. Not gonna go through it all though since it seems mayhem.

Comment: Not only that, but using the wrong identifier qualifiers. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html - there are more errors, but I am getting dizzy going over that mess of theirs. Edit: Along with a variable scoping issue... the list goes on.

Answer (score 0):

I though it was way out of my hands. Well thank you guys I'll start over again it does not help that I'm using tutorials that are Lil older so some syntax has changed and I don't know it that we'll to catch on it . I just wanted to thank everybody for their honest feedback.